# Extending a function continuously from a subset to the whole set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

We are given two sets $E$ and $F$ such that $F \subset E \subset \mathbb{R}$. We are given a continuous function $f$ defined on $F$. Can we always extend it to a continuous function on E (not necessarily unique). I am not getting any ideas as to how to do this . If anyone has any ideas it would be great. Thanks.

Edit 1: As suggested below I am interested in bounded functions.

Comment: As Crostul pointed out in his answer, in general it is not true. However, you may ask yourself what happens if we assume $f$ to be, moreover, bounded.

Comment: Look up the Tietze extension theorem

Comment: @AlbertoDebernardi Also $\sin(1/x)$ cannot be extended, and it is bounded and continuous.

Comment: Not in general. But if $K \subset \Bbb R^n$ is compact and $f: K \to \Bbb R^m$ is a continuous function, then we can always extend $f$ to a continuous function $\tilde f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. $x \mapsto \sin(1/x)$ defined on $F=(0,1)$ cannot be extended continuously to $E=[0,1]$.

Comment: wouldn't $x\mapsto 1/x$ be a simpler example?

Comment: The OP is interested in bounded functions.